# Compiling GCDAsyncSocket for OS X 10.6

Tags: objective-c, osx-snow-leopard

I have troubles with compiling this wonderful TCP library with SDK 10.6.

I get:

```
/Users/cisary/Desktop/AI/AI/TCP/GCDAsyncSocket.m:185:11: error: instance variables may not be placed in class extension
        uint32_t flags;
                 ^
/Users/cisary/Desktop/AI/AI/TCP/GCDAsyncSocket.m:186:11: error: instance variables may not be placed in class extension
        uint16_t config;
```

What does `instance variables may not be placed in class extension` mean?

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to compile for i386? That will not work with GCDAsyncSocket.m as I'm finding it on github. Instance variables defined in class extensions are a modern runtime feature. Try compiling for x86_64.